# SPSS Missing Data

Tags: excel, mean, spss, missing-data

I checked the missing data in SPSS. There were more missing data than the actual missing cases in a variable.

Screenshot:

[image]
 For the first variable, it said there are 171784 missing when there are only 127014 missing (I checked using MS Excel). Moreover, there are actually 341272 cases in total but the sum of valid and missing cases in a variable is only 340296. Why are there lots of missing data? Maybe because of this, the mean values I calculated in SPSS are different from those in MS Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like some values were defined as missing values. As opposed to SPSS, when checking in excel these values are counted as valid and influence the calculation of the average, so the results are different for both comparisons.
To check weather there are values defined as missing, take a look at the "missing" column in the variable view of your dataset.
HTH

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if there are a lot of empty rows in your SPSS Data File that are interpreted as missing data even though they are empty cases. Sometimes importing data to SPSS can cause these problems.

Comment: the empty rows are treated as system missing data. so they are excluded in the calculation